# Auto increment does not work with my appended textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have an autoincrement texbox. For every textbox that I will make, it'll increment by +1. It works on my HTML. But when I apply it to my appended textbox. It is not working anymore. Is there anything I missed? Thank you in advance.

The snippet is just a representation of my function that i want to apply in my appended textbox.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("something");
 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
 list[i].value = (i + 1);
 }
```

```html
// this autoincrement works because my textbox is in html

<input type="text" class="something" name="something"> 
<input type="text" class="something" name="something"> 
<input type="text" class="something" name="something">
```

Html:

```
 <div id="result"> </div>
```

Script: My auto-increment does not work here in my appended textbox

```
 <script>

  

    let ajaxResult = []; // the pushed data will be saved here
    let save_method;
    let table;
    let base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
    let result = [];
    var html = "";
    
    
    
    
    
    function removeDuplicates(result) {
      return Object.values(result.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        acc[curr.player] = acc[curr.player] || curr;
        return acc;
      }, {}))
    }
    
    
    
    const combine = (source) => {
      return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        if (acc[curr.weight]) {
          const levelArr = acc[curr.weight];
          const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
          if (last.length === 2) {
            levelArr.push([curr])
          } else {
            last.push(curr)
          }
        } else {
          acc[curr.weight] = [
            [curr]
          ];
        }
        return acc;
      }, {})
    };
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    const uniquePlayers = removeDuplicates(result);
    
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
    var eventID = $('#eventsssiud').val();
    
    
        //datatables
        table = $("#entry_list1").DataTable({
    
    
            processing: false,
            serverSide: true,
            order: [],
            searching: false,
            paging: false,
            info: false,
    
            ajax: {
                url: "<?php echo site_url('entry/ajax_list')?>",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {eventID:eventID},
                 success: function(data) {
                        
                        
                     
                    result = combine(removeDuplicates(data.data2));
                      
                    
                    
                    
                    
                console.log(result);
                
                
                    
                    var keys = Object.keys(result)
                
                    
            
                    
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    
    
      result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val) {
      var length_ = val.length;
        val.forEach(function(value, index) {
        
    var idaa = value.eventID ; 
    
    
      var count = 1;
    if (idaa == eventID){
        if (length_ == 2) {
    
          var entryIDs = index == 0 ? "entryIDM[]" : "entryIDW[]"
          var players = index == 0 ? "playerM[]" : "playerW[]"
          var weights = index == 0 ? "weightM[]" : "weightW[]"
          var lightBands = index == 0 ? "lightBandM[]" : "lightBandW[]"
          html += `<input type="text" name="${entryIDs}" value="${value.entryID}"> 
                     <input type="text" name="${players}" value="${value.player}">
                     <input type="text" name="${weights}" value="${value.weight}">
                     <input type="text" name="${lightBands}" value="${value.lightBand}">
                     <input type="text" name="eventID" value="${value.eventID}">
                     <input type="text" class="something" name="something"> 
                  
                    
                  
                    
    `
    
          }
          }
          
        })
      })
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div
    
                    
                   
                  
                    
    
                },
            },
    
            "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": [0], //first column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
                {
                    "targets": [-1], //last column
                    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
                },
    
            ],
        });
    });
      
      </script>
```

Comment: In the code snippet that works, you have 3 input elements with `something` class names hence the javascript gets 3 elements to loop through and increment. In the one that doesn't work, you have only one input element with `something` class name

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1yiked0 this is what happens when i append my array to the HTML.

Comment: @UlquiorraSchiffer from where you are getting keys.length?

Comment: I added the full script. My keys.length are generated by the data i fetched from DB

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question. Please review closures in Javascript loops and problems with the `var` keyword in loop scope. `ES6` fixed the issue by introducing `let` keyword. Besides, there are already many solutions to the problem as mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: This is the result of what my testing. https://prnt.sc/1yiked0

Answer (score 0):

Move this snippet at the end of your code. You need to have the elements appended in the html before you can select them with javascript.

```
 var list = document.getElementsByClassName("something");
 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
 list[i].value = (i + 1);
 }
```

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry for the confusion. But my target is auto-increment should work on my appended.

My snippet is just a representation of the function i want to apply on my appended.